# Golang session based authentication

Tags: cookies, go, session-cookies

I am trying to authenticate a user (using email and password) in golang but I am having some problems with sessions. It seems like I cant retrieve the session value from **/login/** to **/** (home) page.

**User Registration**

```
hashedPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(r.Form["passwordSignup"][0]), bcrypt.DefaultCost)

err = c.Insert(&model.UserModel{
  Email:     r.Form["emailSignup"][0],
  Password:  string(hashedPassword),
  CreatedAt: time.Now(),
})

// TODO : should session management be made in here ???
// you can use gorilla sessions if you want as far it works

http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301) // goes to the homepage(only accessed by authenticated users)
```

**Login**

```
if r.Form["emailLogin"][0] == result.Email 
&& bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(result.Password), []byte(r.Form["passwordLogin"][0])) == nil {

  // TODO : Handling the session in here

  http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301) // goes to the home page
} else {
  http.Redirect(w, r, "/login/", 301)
}
```

I checked this links too :
http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/09/05/auth-and-sessions/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0tGnjW_xxI

Comment: Two tips: you should *absolutely* check the error from bcrypt. And you should set the `Path` value of `cookie` to `/` - otherwise it will default to the path where the cookie was first created.

Comment: Take a look to https://github.com/go-authboss/authboss

Comment: Also please avoid doing this 
`if r.Form["emailLogin"][0] == result.Email`, always it is a good habit to form a variable called email = r.Form.Get('emailLogin') rather than using it directly in the if statement

Comment: Guys I removed error checking before hand because I wanted to make it more readable and letting you focus on the relevant part of the question. Anyway thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Importantly, you should check all of your errors - e.g.:

```
- hashedPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(r.Form["passwordSignup"][0]), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
# Check our error, especially for something as important as password hashing
+ hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(r.Form["passwordSignup"][0]), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusBadRequest), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

---

A lot of your relevant cookie code is missing, but here's what it *should* look like:

```
cookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name: "my_app",
        Value: val, // Some encoded value
        Path: "/", // Otherwise it defaults to the /login if you create this on /login (standard cookie behaviour)
        MaxAge: 86400, // One day
}

http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
```

Alternatively, if you use [gorilla/sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) (which I recommend because it correctly authenticates cookies), you would do the following:

```
session, err := store.Get(r, "session-name")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    return
}

session.Options.Path = "/"
session.Values["user"] = user

err := session.Save(r, w)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    return
}

http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 301)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple session management solution which uses Redis or Memcache as your session store, I suggest using [Jeff](https://github.com/abraithwaite/jeff) (disclaimer: I wrote it).

After authenticating a user, you simply add their session like so:

```
func (s Server) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user = Authenticate(r)
    if user != nil {
        // Key must be unique to one user among all users
        err := s.jeff.Set(r.Context(), w, user.Email)
        // handle error
    }
    // finish login
}
```

Subsequent requests will automatically be authenticated once wrapped with the Jeff middleware.  The library was built with simplicity in mind and was built as an alternative to the existing libraries out there.

See the readme for more details on usage and features:

https://github.com/abraithwaite/jeff#usage